# SQL Server Default value for columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

When you use default value for a column in `SQL Server Management Studio` table designer, SSMS change your default and stand Parenthesis around of that (In all editions and all versions of SQL Server). For example if you set `0` as default value, this default changed to `(0)`. I don't know why sql server use parenthesis, and is there a practical reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about in e.g. in the table designer when you're specifying the default?

Answer (score 3):

There are certain types of objects, such as `DEFAULT`s and `CHECK` constraints that SQL Server doesn't store the original, textual form of - in contrast with, say, stored procedures, where you can (absent encryption) always retrieve it in the exact form you gave it to the server - complete with any white space, formatting, comments, etc.

Because SQL Server doesn't store the textual form, it always has to re-generate textual forms to show to users when they ask for such objects. When and where it chooses to insert parentheses can be a bit of a mystery (it's not documented) but since they don't change the meaning of the expression, they shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `0` and `(0)` will evaluate to the same result, so there is nothing to really overcome. Ignore it. It's just how SQL stores them internally and a visibility issue.
It does that is you do it interactively as well. Not sure why does this , but not to worry.