# Can anyone explain the meaning of parenthesis for default?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [db].[Test]
(

[is_available] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Test__is_available]  DEFAULT ((0))

)
```

This is how column is created in my project. Can any one please explain the meaning of **double parenthesis** ((0)). Also I'm trying to understand is DF stands for anything in constraint ?

Comment: May be you are looking for this -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911953/sql-server-default-values-why-with-one-or-two-parentheses

Comment: I like this explanation better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446854/sql-server-default-value-for-columns

Comment: And the DF_ prefix is fairly common as a naming convention for a DEFAULT constraint. There is nothing about the name that affects the behavior at all. It just as easily be called Betelgeuse, Franklin or Hamster (assuming of course that name has not already been used for a constraint).

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your inputs.

Answer (score 3):

in SQL Server `((value))` are shown when scripting DEFAULT values. It doesn't really matter tho, you can still use `()`.